# Prestashop - Send an order event in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, prestashop, google-tag-manager

I'm developing a Prestashop e-commerce and I want integrate it with Google Analytics.

I've created a OrderConfirmationController.php override that provides the order data I want to send to Google Analytics.

Then, in order-confirmation.tpl I'm sending the Analytics event with the Tag Manager code.

It's working almost fine, because most of the users keep tracked. But I see there are orders that aren't being tracked. Maybe when a users pays with PayPal they can exit the browser and Prestashop doesn't render order-confirmation.tpl (so the event is not sent).

Where is the correct place to send the event?

Thank you, greetings.

Comment: Can you provide the way you track the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use hook `actionObjectOrderAddAfter` which is called after an order creation and has all necessary information about the order.

```
public function hookActionObjectOrderAddAfter($order)
{
     // $order is an object
     your code here
}
```

I cannot check exactly your PayPal module but I think it should work

Comment: Thanks! But that's server side, I'm using Google tag manager's javascript library. So how can I use it in this controller? Does it render any HTML? Greetings

Comment: You can invoke your script or even tpl with return statment

Comment: Ok, I will try today. Thank you! ;)

Comment: Sorry about my delay! I forgot to accept your question (sorry!)